# Finding the Roots of a Function

Tags: differential-equations, graphics

I have a system of differential equations, for x [t], y [t] and z [t], I solve the system in a simple way.
However from these solutions I have a function like this:

```
a[t]=(-2*y^2/z[t]^2)(y[t]^2/2+x[t]^2/2)
```

So I solve this equation a[t] and when I plot the graph it looks like this[image: see that it fluctuates a lot]

I'm interested in finding out the coordinates when it intercepts the x axis, that is, it zeroes.
My code for plotting the graph was simple:

```
Plot[a[t], {t, 0, 50}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Look up `Solve`.

Comment: I tried to use Solve, in the form:`Solve[a[t]==0,t]` but it does not generate values, but other graphs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot the pts:

Directly from F1:

[image]

```
Plot[a[x], {x, 0, 50}, MeshFunctions -> {a[x] /. x -> # &}, 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

To get the roots:

```
NSolve[{a[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 50}, x, Reals]
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks worked

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
NSolve[{a[t]==0,0<t<50},t]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not generate values, but other graphs. I can use `Table` for this ?

Comment: @Slayz It cannot generate values because you didn't provide your function `a[x]`